# How to generate single output json object from multiple log lines in logstash filter?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am new to Logstash and Grok filter. I want to parse logs like these -

```
2018-01-11 17:17:16,071 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | CommittedVirtualMemorySize :: 401186816 
2018-01-11 17:17:16,071 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | FreePhysicalMemorySize :: 1751130112 
2018-01-11 17:17:16,072 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | FreeSwapSpaceSize :: 4294967295 
2018-01-11 17:17:16,694 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | ProcessCpuLoad :: -1.0 
2018-01-11 17:17:16,694 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | ProcessCpuTime :: 47471104300 
2018-01-11 17:17:16,698 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | SystemCpuLoad :: 1.0 
2018-01-11 17:17:16,698 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | TotalPhysicalMemorySize :: 4285849600 
2018-01-11 17:17:16,698 | DEBUG | [Thread-2] | com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper:cpuMonitoring(307) | TotalSwapSpaceSize :: 4294967295
```

to a JSON Object like this -

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-01-11 17:17:16,071",
  "log_level": "DEBUG",
  "thread_name": "Thread-2",
  "class": "com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper",
  "method": "cpuMonitoring",
  "line_number": "307",
  "CommittedVirtualMemorySize": "401186816",
  "FreePhysicalMemorySize": "1751130112",
  "FreeSwapSpaceSize": "4294967295",
  "ProcessCpuLoad": "-1.0",
  "ProcessCpuTime": "47471104300",
  "SystemCpuLoad": "1.0",
  "TotalPhysicalMemorySize": "4285849600",
  "TotalSwapSpaceSize": "4294967295"
}
```

As of now my grok pattern is -

> %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \| %{LOGLEVEL:log_level} \| [(?\b[\w-]+\b)] \| %{JAVAFILE:class}:%{JAVAMETHOD:method}(%{NUMBER:line_number}) \| %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}

which provides multiple output lines for each input log line. JSON object looks like this-

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-01-11 17:17:16,071",  
  "log_level": "DEBUG",
  "thread_name": "Thread-2",
  "class": "com.example.monitor.MonitorHelper",
  "method": "cpuMonitoring",
  "line_number": "307",
  "log_message": "CommittedVirtualMemorySize :: 401186816 "
}
```

can you please help me with what I need to look for in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first recommendation is to change the original log output into a single line.

If you can't, and you're using filebeat to ship the file, use FB's [multiline config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) to merge the lines before sending it to logstash.

If you're not using filebeat, you can try to use the [multiline codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) in logstash.

Comment: Thanks. I used FB's multiline config.